# Conversion from java to c# -Covariance and Contravariance

Tags: java, c#, contravariance

```
  public interface IStorage<T> extends Iterable<T> {
        public void copyTo( IStorage<? super T> dest);
        public void copyFrom( IStorage<? extends T> src);
    }
```

Above is the java code that I have to put in c#, for the moment it looks like

```
 interface IStorage<T>:  IEnumerable<T>
    {
     void copyTo( IStorage<? super T> dest);
     void copyFrom( IStorage<? extends T> src);}
```

But I have troubles to find the equivalent  of  when it appears in the parameter of function, I found the in/out or where approaches but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: @Timeless: Was writing an answer as you commented :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic variance in C# is *very* different to generic variance in .NET.

You *sort* of want something like this:

```
public interface IStorage<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // This won't compile - the constraint is on the wrong argument
    void CopyTo<TDest>(IStorage<TDest> dest) where T : TDest
}
```

But that's invalid, as indicated.

As written, the method doesn't really make sense to me - you'd need something else in the interface which would *accept* values of type `T`, at which point `IStorage` could no longer be covariant in `T` anyway.

Given that you can't achieve exactly the same effect, I suggest you think about what you really want to achieve, and consider something like:

```
public interface IStorage<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    void AddAll(IStorage<T> source);
}
```

Or even just:

```
public interface IStorage<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    void AddAll(IEnumerable<T> source);
}
```

So you reverse the target of the call from the source to the destination, at which point the destination can *pull* values from the source, which is more in-keeping with `IEnumerable<T>` being a source of values.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question if it will use IStorage<out T> and I have other methods like : add, search, remove, contains, isEmpty, size it doesn't affect?

Comment: @David: If you have `IStorage<out T>` then you wouldn't be able to have `Add`, no... methods taking parameters "into" the interface don't work with covariance.

Comment: In that case the solution is to rethink things or just let sample T, which is the best approach?

Comment: @David: I don't know what you mean by "or just let sample T". You could have `void AddAll<TSource>(IStorage<TSource> source) where TSource : T` if you wanted.